# In Oracle Database, how do you extract text in-between characters? (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm new at SQL and I have been trying to practice working with Oracle Database.

While working on an activity, I came across one that confounds me -- I am trying to extract specific text from in-between characters. The specific activity that I cannot seem to figure out using these functions is:

For table called **Users** in the column called **Emails**, extract only the email domain (that is, the text in-between @ and .), so that full email addresses:

- mjane@yahoo.com
- jdoe@aol.com
- jbarry@outlook.com

Becomes a new column called **Domains** with the values:

- yahoo
- aol
- outlook

So far I have only been able to write code that isolates only the username to:

- mjane
- jdoe
- jbarry

Using this code:

```
    `select rtrim(Emails,substr(Emails,instr(Emails,'@')))
    from StudentEmails;`
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated! I've been scratching my head about this for hours! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Emails,
              INSTR(Emails, '@') + 1,
              INSTR(Emails, '.') - INSTR(Emails, '@') - 1) AS Domains
FROM Users
```

**Caveat:**

I assume that emails have as single dot separating the domain name from domain type (e.g. `com`, `net`).  If you had an email like `joe@domain.his.us`, then the above query would return `domain` as being the domain.

Comment: You are AMAZING! It worked like a charm -- I can't believe just 4 lines of code got me going around in circles for hours, haha! Clearly I have much to learn -- thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would be another way to go:

```
select substr(regexp_substr(emails,'@[^.]+'),2) domains from users;
```